# Complexity involved in building a single board computer

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, computers, high-speed

Our high school has tasked my and a friend of mine with with building a web connected controller for a hydroponics system. The school has budgeted 5k for us to spend as we like, and we are intent on making our own single board computer (we know this is way overkill) based on the TI AM3874. We both have experience making custom pcbs with AVR based controllers and the like but never with somthing so complex. Additionally we have to have this project completed by late december.

- Does this sit within the realm of possibility?
- What cad package would be the best? all of TI's reference designs are in OrCAD (we can get the high speed version for ~$500, we don't think Eagle or Kicad will cut it)
- What are the pitfalls we should watch out for?

Comment: Using an 800 MHz processor when a 20 MHz uC would do, and spending thousands on development when a few hundred could buy a solution off the shelf are not good engineering.

Comment: What test equipment do we need to debug it? we were considering a 1ghz scope with the proper high impedance probes recommended by our reseller, this is not a commercial product so we do not intend to sell it, my understanding is that it does not need to be FCC approved is this correct?, also we were planning to put in a medial enclosure which (should?) shield the RF interference. if not how can we tell if it produced this interference? we have a hack rf could we build a faraday cage for 5ghz and sweep the spectrum and see if we can find anything?

Comment: I've moved my comments to an answer. So you go through a few design iterations to get it reliable. You put it into a Faraday cage, sweep the spectrum, and find serious emissions. You have a week left, what do you do? Some kid blogs pictures of the thing with your names attached. It gets stored somewhere on the Internet forever. Every interview you go to asks you about it ...

Comment: Instead, consider spending the $5k on something like [Aquaponics](http://acara.environment.umn.edu/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/BlueFoodFishGreens_BusinessPlan.pdf). They claim to be at the cutting edge of sustainable, profitable, food production. They claim for $5k they can get started. That experience might convert you to 'gold dust'.

Comment: I am not necessarily talking about FCC approval. In the UK, if someone is running a sufficiently electromagnetically noisy device that it is a nuisance, a part of the government gets involved. I believe the same is true in the USA. On the converse side, an occasional glitch might be hard to track down in the time available. Time might be the hardest constraint to solve.

Comment: December 2014 (3 months) is a very aggressive schedule to design and test a working PCB with a 684-pin BGA (Ball Grid Array) pacakge, even for someone with many years of EE/CompE design experience. And this doesn't include software and firmware development time. (Not a duplicate but relevant to this type of PCB layout: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/127597/custom-fpga-pcb-design-tips )

Comment: Just use a raspberry pi and be done with it.

Comment: Do what real R&D engineers do: collect use cases, develop requirements, elaborate the design, do feasibility assessments (that's what this question is about).  Don't get bent on the horsepower of the processor.  As you elaborate the design, you will probably notice a few things: the devil is in the software (no less so than in the hardware), 3 moths is not a lot of time (even if all you have to produce is a decent prototype).  P.S.  $5k is not too shabby for a high school project.  I'm kind of curious where is a high school like that.

Comment: @Nick Alexeev we got like 20k to set up the hydroponics system there is a team of kids developing the hydroponics system, the associated hardware (valves sensors etc), yet another team doing all the software (except for the low level stuff), and us doing the board.

Comment: You don't have three months.  You need to allow several weeks **after the board is 100% done** for integration testing, making sure your board work smoothly with the rest of the system.  You are trying to do **way too much**.  Buy an off-the-shelf SBC.  Go overboard and get a Raspberry Pi or BeagleBone Black instead of a PIC18, and have some fun learning Linux.  Spend your time gettig the software right.

Comment: @NickAlexeev, if they did all that, it would be December before they drew the first wire on a schematic.

Comment: I'd like to see these students succeed, and I'm concerned that the scope of the project may be too broad for the time allowed. Using a smaller, more easily solderable package would help. Fewer components and fewer nets leaves fewer things that can go wrong. Or just buying ready-made COTS board like Arduino / Raspberry Pi / ARM dev board would help mitigate a lot of the development risks.

Comment: @ThePhoton  Are you alluding to the fact that these are high school students that lack R&D experience, but don't lack other commitments in life?

Comment: As an engineering instructor who's walked hundreds of engineering students through design projects like what you're describing, I'll chime in, as the discussion seems to be going this way.  If your goal is to provide your customers with a working system that is OK to actually use, starting with trying to build a single board computer is not a good idea.  There's plenty of design challenges that remain if you start with an available SBC

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others have commented, your aim of making this kind of SBC is probably far too high for your experience, equipment, schedule, and maybe even budget.

But you are young, you think you can surely do it, all those old folks don't have the spirit, etc.

I suggest you have it both ways: get a RaspberryPi (or something similar, but a PI is as good a choice as the alternatives), and use it to develop a (fully working) proof of concept for the total system. If your SBC project is feasible, you should be able to do the Pi version in ~ 10% of the time and budget. And it will give the other teams in the project a chance to experience a version of the full system early on. Never underestimate the value of an early prototype for user feedback!

If the PI prototype is successful and you have sufficient time, budget and motivation left you can continue with your SBC. By that time we will surely see you back here on SE with more detailed questions. If the SBC development fails (of course it won't, but just in the off chance), the hydroponic system is not without a controller, and you are not without a good result to get your marks for.

Comment: Thanks, I think we might just build a board using the raspberry pie compute module, then later if we can develop the single board computer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

That TI AM3874 runs at **50x** the frequency of AVRs you have experience with.

PCBs don't work the same way at those frequencies.

'Works-first-time' is not the way to think about it.

Testing is *much* harder at those frequencies.

It is only 3x from WiFi, Bluetooth, etc. frequencies, and less than 3x from mobile phones. So you should seriously think about electromagnetic emissions and sensitivity to interference. For example, it might generate so much interference that it can't be 'web connected', or every time anyone walks near it and their mobile phone rings, it might suffer a glitch.

Things to consider:
1a) How much will the test equipment cost to debug it?
1b) How will you ensure it is not a source of electromagnetic interference, or sensitive to electromagnetic emissions?
1c) If it is unreliable, with occasional failures, what is the fall-back approach?
2a) How much might it cost to ensure it is compliant with USA/EU/... electromagnetic regulations? or
2b) How much might it cost to deal with the FCC/... if 2a is inadequate?

Designing a PCB which appears to be capable of working may be the least of the obstacles.

Edit 2:
I think lack of time, money and experience may be too many constraints for something that runs at 1GHz.

How might I approach this?

Edit 3:
My first priority would be to ensure the hydroponics project succeeds. I would try to do as little as practical, as quickly as practical to ensure it succeeds. That might be an off-the-shelf solution.

After that, there should be plenty of time, and several ways to progress. One way might be to dig into the practical operation of the hydroponics project, and maybe discover something that needs much better electronics or software. My experience is projects reveal unexpected challenges and opportunities once they are operating. I find these surprises are often much more interesting than the initial brief.

Another way might to build a more fun piece of electronics, maybe for a complementary project.

What might I build, knowing hydroponics is working, and nothing else is needed?

- Aim to design something which would be *clearly* much better than an AVR, 
  *and* very likely to work. 60MHz up, with good ADC, and peripherals?
- Maybe use an MCU, and not a SoC, then the PCB should be easier to get
  right.
- Maybe use external memory with an MCU, and make it more SoC like, or 
  Quad-SPI memory, or FRAM for non-volatile 'data logging'
- Powerful peripherals might be much more useful than raw computer
  power. Cypress PSoC? It has programmable digital and analogue peripherals, and uses VHDL.
- Choose an MCU that has a good tool chain, but is not too popular.
  Then it'd be easier to justify and defend build instead of buy.
  That probably means ARM-based or MIPS-based. PIC32MZ?
- Must have a usable development board, it's very useful to have a working
  system for comparison
- Must have hardware debugger, toggling pins only goes so far
- Should have good technical support, just in case
- Should *all* be doable in *under 1 month*, people typically underestimate
  effort and duration by more than 3.14x (geddit?)
- Maybe an MCU company that offers internships and sponsorships through
  college :-)

An aside:
Engineers try to operate rationally. Engineers are expected not to waste money 'reinventing the wheel'. Personally, I would be unhappy to discover someone had spent 10x more than necessary to do a simple job. I would be even less happy if it meant they failed to deliver on time, or delivered a poor result, or failed a team. It seems like a high risk strategy for little reward.

The multi-discipline project described in the question and comments, is less about technology, and more about social interaction, team work, staying focused on the project and its participants, and helping to drive forward.

If I were interviewing, and discovered a poor history about a candidate, I would require a good explanation. It might even influence my hiring decision. The Internet provides ways for some things to remain public for a long time. So I would ask you, please think carefully before doing something which might have visible repercussions in an area which might become relevant or important.

Comment: Good warnings, though note that it's for a high school, so which is the point, a working hydroponics system or the experience the students get from designing a single-board computer? Even if it doesn't work in the end, it's a valuable experience and I doubt it's a career killer. For a business it could be, but they're students. Then again, I suspect it *will* fail if they're dealing with 800MHz signals. 50-100MHz might be a different story. :-)

Comment: "Engineers try to operate rationally" - for various definitions of rational. Plenty of engineers will spend weeks creating a spiffy machine to automate 3 minutes of manual labor, because it's fun.

Comment: @Rennex - I agree, it is *unlikely* to be a career killer. However, wouldn't it be much better to both stretch *and* shine? I've added a section to illustrate my suggestions for compromise. Something which would go *way beyond* AVR, maybe unusual enough to justify build over buy, and broad enough to learn a lot. I think 60MHz+ should be doable.

Comment: @whatsisname - If it were their money, an independent project, with plenty of time, then I could agree that fun is enough justification. It is not pleasant to read about students who have tried and failed to do projects which were doomed from the start. I have written to a college asking how did it go so wrong? Everyone looks bad. I think there isn't enough time, money and experience available, and it looks like failure will have knock-on effects. However, there are  interesting projects, with good odds for success. I'm impressed by folks who have been clever, and ensured success. They shine.

Comment: The idea that as a high schooler developing or attempting to develop a single board computer over buying a solution would make me less likely to get a job seems silly, unless I completely mis-understand the whole idea

Comment: Do you agree that the spending 10x more (of someone else's) money than necessary, to build something which is 40x more computer than necessary, using technology beyond available experience, under extreme time pressure, that is part of a larger project, is not good engineering?

Comment: While its high school, and there's plenty of time for the OP to secure the sense of realism, if the person gets to the interviewing stage and "I wanted to build a simple control system, so I started by building a single board computer" comes up, the interview will not go well.  However "I built an SBC while I was in high school" might.

Comment: @ScottSeidman - Success has a way of improving situations. Alternatively, pulling an entire project down has a way of magnifying mistakes. I would not like to cause a bunch of kids with articulate parents to fail on a key project. They might all expect and need success. So saying "I designed a controller for this $20k hydroponics project in a few weeks. That worked fine. Then we discovered a *much* better way to control it. I'd done the first board so quickly, I had time to design a better board which 'nailed it'. We won ...." A team player like that would impress me more than an SBC designer.

Comment: I think we're largely in agreement here. If they start with the design of the SBC, they will not successfully complete their project.  Even if they do, if they go to an interview like that and portray that as a successfully completed project, the interviewer will not be impressed.

Comment: @ScottSeidman - Yes, copacetic. Also tcrosley makes the point, the project might take weeks to integrate and test. That is usually when 'killer' problems are discovered. Starting with an off-the-shelf solution, and integrating a key use-case very early might ensure the project discovers problems early enough that it can recover and work. Good in interviews, good in life. A student who experienced and understands how to make a multi-discipline team project be successful, rather than focusing on a small piece is IMHO well ahead of the rest. Good engineers deliver working systems and low stress.